# Polymer: using css-classes in iron-iconset-svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, polymer

I'm trying to create a colored `iron-icon-set`. Due to technical restrictions, I'm unable to set the color `iron-icon`.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<iron-iconset-svg name="myiconset" size="24">
  <svg>
    <style>
        .green {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <g id="flag-red"><path d="M14.4 6L14 4H5v17h2v-7h5.6l.4 2h7V6z" style="color:red"/></g>
        <g id="flag-green"><path d="M14.4 6L14 4H5v17h2v-7h5.6l.4 2h7V6z" class="green"/></g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

I'd like to use classes for reusing the same color on multiple icons rather than repeating the same `style="color:XXX"` on dozens of icons.

Of course I'd love to use the already existing styles, but from [what I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297000/iron-iconset-svg-and-var-primary-text-color) so far this won't work, so I didn't try it at all.

Nevertheless: Is there a way to use css-classes inside a `iron-iconset-svg`?

Answer (score 1):

SVG does not use the color CSS property, it uses fill and stroke instead.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<iron-iconset-svg name="myiconset" size="24">
  <svg>
    <style>
        .green {
            fill: green;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <g id="flag-red"><path d="M14.4 6L14 4H5v17h2v-7h5.6l.4 2h7V6z" style="fill:red"/></g>
        <g id="flag-green"><path d="M14.4 6L14 4H5v17h2v-7h5.6l.4 2h7V6z" class="green"/></g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#flag-red"/>
  <use transform="translate(50,0)" xlink:href="#flag-green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: thanks for correcting the missuse of css-styles. Chrome seems not to care wether you use fill or color. Nevertheless the css class is not applied when used as icon for icon-icon.